# Profile picture in registration form WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, registration

I have custom built registration form and i want an option were in a user can upload and display his/her image as a profile picture. Now  once a user is registered and have uploaded the profile image then in that case if the user comment on a blog post on the same website then the same profile picture will be displayed. Can you give a script for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if what you're looking for is how to implement gravatars: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Gravatars